# Terminal Based Blackjack

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, console, playing-cards

This is my attempt at a terminal based blackjack game. Currently, the game does not support betting, although I intend to add it in the future.

I would very much appreciate general feedback, but I am especially interested in the following:

- Comments on docstrings and type hints, as this is my first time trying to properly use either
- Advice about printing long strings to the terminal. I am at present using \ line continuation characters to avoid overly long lines in the code, but this seems to either require weird indentation or printing excess whitespace to the terminal.
- I intend to, in the future, use many of these classes to write a GUI based blackjack game with tkinter. If I've made any decisions that will make that kind of reuse challenging, advice would be great!

```
import random


SUITS_DICT = {
    'spades': 0x1f0a0,
    'hearts': 0x1f0b0,
    'diamonds': 0x1f0c0,
    'clubs': 0x1f0d0,
}

KNIGHT_RANK = 12


class Card():
    """A class used to represent a playing card"""

    def __init__(self, number: int, suit: str):
        self.suit = suit
        self.number = number

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Card({self.number}, {self.suit})'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        cardNo = SUITS_DICT[self.suit] + self.number
        return chr(cardNo) if self.number < KNIGHT_RANK else chr(cardNo + 1)

    def blackjack_value(self) -> int:
        """Returns the card's value in blackjack"""
        return self.number if self.number < 10 else 10


CUT_CARD = Card(0, 'spades')


class CardCollection(list):
    """A subclass of list for collections of playing cards"""

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        outStr = ''
        for card in self:
            outStr += str(card) + ' '
        return outStr


class Deck(CardCollection):
    """A class to represent a deck (or multiple decks) of cards"""

    def __init__(self, deckMultiple: int):
        self.deckMultiple = deckMultiple
        self.fill_deck()

    def cut(self):
        random.shuffle(self)
        self.insert(random.randrange(-75, -60), CUT_CARD)

    def fill_deck(self):
        """Fills the deck with cards"""
        for i in range(self.deckMultiple):
            for suit in SUITS_DICT:
                for n in range(1, 14):
                    self.append(Card(n, suit))

    def refresh(self):
        """Removes any cards remaining in the deck,
        and fills it with fresh cards"""
        self.clear()
        self.fill_deck()

    def deal_to(self, hand: CardCollection):
        """Removes a card from the deck, and adds it to another card
        collection. If the card drawn is a card used to mark where
        the deck is cut, refreshes the deck."""
        card = self.pop(0)
        if card == CUT_CARD:
            self.refresh()
            hand.append(self.pop(0))
        else:
            hand.append(card)


class BlackjackHand(CardCollection):
    """A Class to represent a hand of cards in blackjack"""

    def __init__(self, isDealer: bool = False):
        self.isDealer = isDealer

    def score(self) -> int:
        """Returns the hands value in blackjack"""
        aceCount = 0
        total = 0
        for card in self:
            if card.number == 1:
                aceCount += 1
            else:
                total += card.blackjack_value()
        for i in range(aceCount):
            if total + 11 > 21:
                total += 1
            else:
                total += 11
        return total

    def evaluate(self):
        """Returns the cards reuslt in blackjack"""
        if self.score() == 21 and len(self) == 2:
            return 'blackjack'
        elif self.score() < 22:
            return self.score()
        else:
            return 'bust'


class HandList(list):
    """A class to represent a group of hands"""

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        strList = []
        for hand in self:
            strList.append(str(hand))
        return '    '.join(strList)


class Blackjack():
    """A class to represent a game of blackjack"""

    def __init__(self, noDecks: int = 6):
        self.reset_hands()
        self.shoe = Deck(noDecks)
        self.shoe.cut()

    def reset_hands(self):
        """Removes all hands associated with the game and creates empty ones"""
        self.playerHands = HandList()
        self.playerHands.append(BlackjackHand())
        self.dealerHand = BlackjackHand(True)

    def hit(self, hand: BlackjackHand):
        """Moves one hand from the shoe to a hand"""
        self.shoe.deal_to(hand)

    def split(self, hand: BlackjackHand):
        """Splits a hand containing two cards of the same value into two hands"""
        if (len(hand) == 2 and
                hand[0].blackjack_value() == hand[-1].blackjack_value()):
            self.playerHands.append(BlackjackHand())
            self.playerHands[-1].append(hand.pop(-1))
            self.hit(hand)
            self.hit(self.playerHands[-1])
        else:
            raise ValueError

    # Doubling down will be implemented with betting
    # def doubleDown(self, hand: BlackjackHand):
    #     """"""
    #     if len(hand) == 2:
    #         self.hit(hand)
    #     else:
    #         raise ValueError

    def player_actions_text(self) -> list:
        """Allows the player to make their moves,
        returning a list of the results"""
        results = []
        for hand in self.playerHands:
            print(f'Your hand is {hand}, which scores {hand.score()}')
            while hand.score() < 22:
                playerAction = input('What would you like to do? ').lower()
                match playerAction:
                    case 'hit':
                        self.hit(hand)
                    # Doubling down will be implemented with betting
                    # case 'double down':
                    #     try:
                    #         game.doubleDown(hand)
                    #         break
                    #     except ValueError:
                    #         print('You can only double down on the initial deal!')
                    case 'split':
                        try:
                            self.split(hand)
                        except ValueError:
                            print('You can only split two cards with \
                                the same value!')
                    case 'stand':
                        break
                    case _:
                        print("That's not a valid move!")
                print(f'Your hand is {hand}, which scores {hand.score()}.')
            else:
                print(f"Your hand is {hand}, which scores {hand.score()}. \
                        You're bust!")
            results.append(hand.evaluate())
        return results

    def dealer_actions_text(self):
        """Performs the dealer's moves, and returns the dealer's result"""
        while self.dealerHand.score() < 17:
            print("That's less than 17, so the dealer hits")
            self.hit(self.dealerHand)
            print(f"The dealer's hand is {self.dealerHand}, \
                    which scores {self.dealerHand.score()}.")
        else:
            if self.dealerHand.score() > 21:
                print(f"The dealer's hand is {self.dealerHand}, \
                        which scores {self.dealerHand.score()}. They're bust!")
            else:
                print(f"The dealer's hand is {self.dealerHand}. \
                        They stand on {self.dealerHand.score()}.")
            return self.dealerHand.evaluate()


def declare_results(playerResults: list, dealerResult: list):
    """Prints the results of a game to the terminal"""
    for i in range(len(playerResults)):
        handNumber = i+1
        if (playerResults[i] == 'blackjack' and
                dealerResult == 'blackjack'):
            print(f"Hand {handNumber} and the dealer both got blackjack. \
                    It's a push!")
        elif playerResults[i] == 'blackjack':
            print(f"Hand {handNumber} got blackjack and won!")
        elif playerResults[i] == 'bust':
            print(f"Hand {handNumber} went bust and lost!")
        elif dealerResult == 'blackjack':
            print(f"Hand {handNumber} scored {playerResults[i]} \
                    and the dealer got blackjack. Hand {handNumber} lost!")
        elif dealerResult == 'bust':
            print(f"Hand {handNumber} scored {playerResults[i]} \
                    and the dealer went bust. Hand {handNumber} won!")
        else:
            print(f"Hand {handNumber} scored {playerResults[i]} \
                    and the dealer scored {dealerResult}")
            if playerResults[i] == dealerResult:
                print("It's a push!")
            elif playerResults[i] > dealerResult:
                print(f"Hand {handNumber} wins!")
            elif playerResults[i] < dealerResult:
                print(f"Hand {handNumber} loses!")
            else:
                raise Exception


def main():
    my_game = Blackjack()
    while True:
        for i in range(2):
            for hand in my_game.playerHands:
                my_game.hit(hand)
            my_game.hit(my_game.dealerHand)
        print(f"The dealer's facing card is {my_game.dealerHand[0]}")
        playerResults = my_game.player_actions_text()
        print(f"The dealer's hand is {my_game.dealerHand}, \
              which scores {my_game.dealerHand.score()}.")
        dealerResult = my_game.dealer_actions_text()
        declare_results(playerResults, dealerResult)
        if input('Do you want to play another round? (y/n) ').lower() == 'y':
            my_game.reset_hands()
        else:
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `Deck.__init__()` should immediately raise fatal error if `deck_multiple < 2`. Else we have a ticking time bomb where `cut()` will blow up with IndexError.  If app developer wrote a bug it should be easy to find, pointing blame at the immediate cause rather than waiting for some innocent caller to trigger the bomb.  Rename the class to plural `Decks`, or to `Shoe`. Rename `noDecks` to `num_decks` for clarity. Having `evaluate` return `str` or `int` wouldn't be my first choice. Rather than `'bust'`, consider returning `0`, `float('NaN')`, or `None`. Spell the parameter: `blackjack_hand`

Comment: The `[player, dealer]` list of hands makes sense until we split(). Consider instead modeling it as a dict with keys of `'player'`, `'dealer'`, and after a split `'player2'`.

Answer (score 2):

Run your code through a PEP8 linter. The most frequent issue is variable naming for which you use lowerCamelCase but this needs to be changed to lower_snake_case.

`SUITS_DICT` is a neat trick, but has a few issues:

- you should add documentation, something like

```py
Suit = Literal[
    'spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'hearts',
]

# This is a dictionary of Unicode suit codepoints. The codepoints themselves
# don't represent anything and need to be added to the card number.
SUITS_DICT: dict[Suit, int] = {
    'spades':   0x1f0a0,  # then  (+1, ace) through  (+14, king)
    'hearts':   0x1f0b0,  # similarly for the other suits
    'diamonds': 0x1f0c0,
    'clubs':    0x1f0d0,
}
```

- it's not very legible or [accessible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_accessibility). The card values and suits are extremely small and require zooming in; and there's more risk that the user's font cannot render these symbols. So as neat of a trick as it is, it's probably not as well-advised as to simply print the value in regular numerals aside the suit symbol.

You're missing several type hints. Anything (including constructors) that doesn't have a return value needs to be marked `-> None`.

`()` after a class declaration is redundant and should be deleted.

`CardCollection.__str__` is likely to suffer from O(n^2) runtime due to repeated string concatenation. Options to solve this include a `join` on a generator. `HandList` is slightly better, but needn't construct an in-memory list; just use a bare generator i.e. `'    '.join(str(hand) for hand in self)`.

`isDealer` seems unused so delete it.

The user interface is a little hostile to usability. When you ask what the user would like to do, you should print the available options.

This:

```
                        print('You can only split two cards with \
                            the same value!')
```

is unlikely to do your intent. After the newline-escape, the string will include all of the indentation spaces. Instead,

```
print('You can only split two cards with '
      'the same value!')
```

`for i in range(2)` should replace `i` with `_` since it's unused.